# Do you windsurf and kitesurf on the sea or in the sea?

Tags: prepositions

- Do you windsurf and kitesurf *on* the lake or *in* the lake?
- Do you windsurf and kitesurf *on* the sea or *in the* sea?

Which preposition is used for *the sea* and which for *the lake*? I need help.

> I practice windsurfing and kitesurfing *in* the lake.

or

> I practice windsurfing and kitesurfing *on* the lake.

Comment: Your question title says "sea" and your examples say "lake". Which is it?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Does the answer change with the two different objects("lake" and "sea")?

Comment: Yes: see Janus' answer.

Comment: If you're a good windsurfer, you'll windsurf ***on*** the lake. If you're a beginner, you are likely to end up ***in*** the lake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title and question ask two different things. You kite- and windsurf *on* a lake, but *in* the ocean.

(I wouldn’t normally say that you do either in the sea, though I can’t quite figure out why ‘ocean’ sounds more right to me than ‘sea’ here.)

Comment: So "you [can't] do either in the" English Channel, which is neither lake nor ocean, but is a 'sea'!

Comment: Neither in the Mediterranean sea :(

Comment: Obviously, you can say that you go surfing in the English Channel, or in the Mediterranean. But if I substituted a generic term for a body of water for those, I think I would automatically say “surfing in the ocean” for both, even though they’re not. This is just my own personal gut feeling, however—others might use “surfing in the sea” with no feeling of awkwardness.