# Is it 'under' or 'in' the sea?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

When thinking about a submarine (or fish, or anything).  Is the object under the sea or in the sea. To my mind it is in the sea, as being under something suggests exactly that.

A boat can be said to be 'in the sea', but according to a lot of comments on another question here, that would mean that the boat has sunk beneath the surface of the water (not a good place for a boat to be!).

Comment: You can say either. Both are somewhat ambiguous. "In the sea" could mean "on the surface of the sea" or "passing through the sea" (e.g. an island in the sea). "Under the sea" could mean "beneath the surface of the sea" or "beneath the seabed." In practice, I'd guess the first is more ambiguous since people rarely talk about things beneath the seabed.

Comment: I read the answers to what might be considered a duplicate, but do not feel that they have answered my question.  However if people feel this is a duplicate I will of course remove the question or re-word.  Thanks.

Comment: Could you make another edit to add a bit more information about what is causing you trouble? What is the question with comments that you mention? I don't think it is the one I linked to; I don't see any comments there saying a boat "in the sea" can only refer to a boat that has sunk.

Comment: Another related question: [what does “cast in the sea” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314027)

Comment: Is the comment you are talking about the one here? [Do you windsurf and kitesurf on the sea or in the sea?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120026) "If you're a good windsurfer, you'll windsurf on the lake. If you're a beginner, you are likely to end up in the lake. – Peter Shor "

Comment: @sumelic - it might save you a lot of trouble if you just come straight out and say you don't like my question.  If others are also against it I will remove it - but I believe you have now made your point.

Comment: I won't say that because I don't mean that. I retracted my close vote because you said your question hasn't been resolved by the answers to the linked question. I just am confused about what exactly the question is. What kind of answer are you looking for? What are the "lot of comments on another question here" that you mention? I would like to read them and the associated question so I can learn more background information about this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THESE ARE SOME LINGUISTIC CONVENTIONS which form part of the tradition of English usage. A ship sails ON the sea. A fish lives IN the sea. A submarine travels UNDER (the surface of) the sea. Of course, literally speaking, all three are IN the water, but the language treats them as distinctly different entities and therefore assigns them appropriately different expressions.

Comment: Hi, great answer, which deserved a mark up.  I have to disagree though.  I live on a boat (to some people a ship), I do not sail on the sea, I go 'to sea', I am 'at sea', and yes, I sail both on and in the sea.  However, your comment about the submarine I feel is correct.  You have though answered as far as linguistic conventions allow, many thanks.

Comment: You are most welcome. A ship 'sails on' the sea; a sailor 'goes to sea' and he is 'at sea' till he returns to land; he may like to swim 'in the sea'; and those who are just learning English are (therefore) ALL AT SEA! It is fine details like these that make English such a great language.

Comment: Yeah, that is brilliant!

Comment: Just read your bio -seriously, you have a masterly grasp of Englsih - check out my webs, and any ideas on either drop me a line.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Learning any language is a life's work and I have been concentrating mainly on English